# Is it bad to run on a (relatively) full stomach?

Tags: running, long-distance-running

I usually drink about a liter of water after waking up every morning and go running (2x/week 5k and 1x/week 10k+) shortly (15-20 mins) after. I never feel any discomfort due to the full stomach. But recently I was warned this is "bad"; are there any physiological reasons behind this, or merely a matter of convention?

Edit (after answers): As I found out recently, this sort of thing (running on a full stomach, e.g. shortly after lunch) is done often enough in various military academies/bootcamps. So it is really unlikely to be physically harmful.

Comment: I'm not voting to close, as I can see the general "don't go swimming after you eat" type "wisdom" tossed around which seems to have some ring over here too. And I'd imagine it's answerable, related to potential abdominal cramping of some sort.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the point of the question. Maybe it could have been phrased better...?

Comment: it made sense to me as worded. Regardless, welcome to fitness.stackexchange.com and feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no known physiological reasons that drinking water before running is bad.

Some people can't handle water juggling around in their stomach while they're running. It can cause a lot of discomfort or even muscle cramps. Some people may even get a bit sick from it. You can also hear and feel the water sloshing around if you drink enough of it which can be kind of freaky. So in that sense some people feel it's bad because it may be for them. However, this is a matter of weak tolerance to running on a full stomach. It doesn't mean there are any detrimental effects occurring.

Answer (score 4):

**It's not bad for you but it's not optimal either.**

It's not bad for you to drink this much and go workout instantly after, but it takes some time for your body to actually absorb all of the water and hydrate your body.

You're better off drinking this amounf of water up to 30 minutes before working out. During the workout drink little sips of water to keep you hydrated throughout the workout.