# Physical routine after having plenty of water

Tags: workout-routines, water

I got this doubt when I feel little disturbance in the stomach after my pushup routine.

I drunk a litre of water and started doing my pushup routine and felt odd as told above.

Is it a bad idea to do my routine after having a litre of water?

Answer (score 1):

As in the answer [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/36509/is-it-bad-to-run-on-a-relatively-full-stomach/36510#36510). It does not hurt you to drink water before physical activity. In the short term, it can cause muscle cramps because all that water moves around. It can also sound weird because it's sometimes possible to actually hear the water sloshing around.

Some people have iron stomachs and won't have any of those uncomfortable effects. Others may get them almost immediately. Supposedly it is possible to train yourself to handle large amounts of food/water while exercising. You would train it much like anything.  Start with a quarter litre for a couple weeks.  Then half a litre, then 3 quarters of a litre and so on.

However, there is no benefit to cutting a workout short because you get a stomach cramp from drinking too much. There is also no real reason to drink so much unless you're about to go out on some long (> 1 hour) endurance run/bike/swim/intense physical activity.